# How can you initialize a range of values into a variable. e.g. 80 to 100=A and 75 to 79=B etc

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, controls, statements

** The problem is it doesn't work since it keeps printing an A for all averages. Even though one gets an average of 30 it still says that your average is 30 and your grade is A.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define newline '\n';
int main()
{
    int studentno;
    string name;
    float marks[8];
    float sum=0;
    double average;


    cout<<"Please enter your full names"<<newline;
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Please enter your student number :"<<newline;
    cin>>studentno;
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the marks of the student :";
        cin>>marks[i];
        cout<<endl;
        sum += marks[i];
    }

    average = sum/8;

    #So from this point, I have subdivided the sections into different ranges whereby if a person has an average of 85 then its an A, and if an average of 76 then its an A-. The problem is it doesn't work since it keeps printing an A for all averages.  

    if(80.0<= average <=100)
    {
      cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is A "<<endl;
    }

    else if(75.0<= average <=79.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is A- "<<endl;
    }

    else if(70.0<= average <=74.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is B+ "<<endl;
    }

    else if(65.0<= average <=69.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is B "<<endl;
    }

    else if(60.0<= average <=64.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is B- "<<endl;
    }

    else if(55.0<= average <=59.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is C+ "<<endl;
    }

    else if(50.0<= average <=54.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is C "<<endl;
    }

    else if(45.0<= average <=49.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is C- "<<endl;
    }

    else if(40.0<= average <=44.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is D+ "<<endl;
    }

    else if(35.0<= average <=39.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is D "<<endl;
    }

    else if(31.0<= average <=34.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is D- "<<endl;
    }

    else if(0.0<= average <=30.9)
    {
        cout<<"Your average is :"<<average<<" and your grade is E "<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Invalid marks input please check again and correct where you went wrong"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**This is the output**

```
Please enter your full names
James Bond
Please enter your student number :
007
Please enter the marks of the student :12
Please enter the marks of the student :20
Please enter the marks of the student :30
Please enter the marks of the student :23
Please enter the marks of the student :24
Please enter the marks of the student :21
Please enter the marks of the student :7
Please enter the marks of the student :13
Your average is :18.75 and your grade is A
```

*As you can see, it says an average mark of 18.75 is equivalent to an A which isn't what i wrote on the code.*

Comment: You could use a [`std::pair<float>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) to represent the range borders.

Comment: `#define newline '\n';` Uh. Avoid macros when you can. If you really want to, use `const char newline = '\n';`, but I'd just write `\n` directly.

Answer (score 3):

This condition

```
if(80.0<= average <=100)
```

does not check whether `average` is between 80 and 100.

Instead, the condition evaluates to `if((80.0<= average) <=100)` which results in either `if(0 <=100)` or `if(1 <=100)`, both of which are always true, and so you always get the result that the average grade is `A`.

The correct way to do the check is:

```
if(80.0 <= average && average <= 100)
```